# I can't add a close tag to a list element in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a To-do List, but I can't add a close tag to a list element in js. When I add the marked 5 lines of code in js my code doesn't work and I can't add a new list. Can you help me? Why it doesn't work, I didn't understand. I'm missing something..

I created a To-do List, but I can't add a close tag to a list element in js. When I add the marked 5 lines of code in js my code doesn't work and I can't add a new list. Can you help me? Why it doesn't work, I didn't understand. I'm missing something..

```js
let form = document.querySelector('#form');
let reset = document.querySelector('#reset');
let myList = document.querySelector('#myList');
let text = document.querySelector('#text');
let submit = document.querySelector('#submit');

submit.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let liDOM = document.createElement('li')
  liDOM.className = 'list-group-item'
  liDOM.innerHTML = `${text.value[0].toUpperCase()}${text.value.slice(1)}`;
  myList.appendChild(liDOM);

  // If I add this 5 code lines, it doesn't work. WHY?
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  var text = document.createElement('\u00D7');
  span.className = 'close';
  span.appendChild(text);
  liDOM.appendChild(span);
});

myList.addEventListener('click', function(item) {
  if (item.target.tagName = 'li') {
    item.target.classList.toggle('checked');
  }
})

let counter = 0;

function myFunction() {
  while (counter < myList.childElementCount) {
    myList.removeChild(myList.firstChild);
  }
}
```

```css
ul li.checked {
  background: #888;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>To Do List</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form">

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 mt-5">

          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="input-group">

                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="text" placeholder="What will you do today?">

                <div class="input-group-append">
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" id="submit">Ekle</button>
                  <button onclick="myFunction()" type="submit" id="reset" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Sıfırla</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card mt-3">
            <div class="card-header">My List</div>
            <ul id="myList" class="list-group list-group-flush">

            </ul>


          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks like a [hoisting issue](https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/?utm_source=javascriptweekly&utm_medium=email). Rename your `text` variable in that handler to something else.

Comment: What is `document.createElement('\u00D7')` supposed to be? That's not a valid tag name.

Comment: That looks like the text you want in the span. Just use `span.innerText = '\u00D7'`

Comment: Thanks to you, I understood what I missed. Thank you so much again! I'm grateful!
@Andy

Comment: @Barmar Thanks to you, I understood what I missed. Thank you so much again! I'm grateful!

Answer (score 1):

First of all good job, this was in nearly working condition and looks great.

There seemed to be a few minor problems with the implementation.

First, it is unusual/counterintuitive to have 2 different buttons each with type submit.

I would assume only first one should have type='submit'. The second one for presumably clearing the input should be type='button'. I also think they should have different styles to help warn the user that they have very different functionality.

Also, since the button has a submit functionality you don't need to also add an onclick functionality. It is very good to have an on submit functionality on the form and the single button with type='submit' as this allows the enter key to add a ToDo item.

Finally, the main focus of your problem was just that the `text` variable was already defined and you can't create an Element with the type × that is not an HTML type. See all the HTML elements on Mozilla Development search your favorite Search Engine for MDN Mozilla and within that search HTML for a list of current Legal HTML elements. It is very unlikely that an element will not be a word or abbreviation of some kind so that immediately tipped me off that: `×` was not an element tag that you can create they're more like (div, span, script, p, b, i). I think you meant for that to be the content of another span element that you wanted to create. Once you solved those 2 issues your code works!

I would just recommend that you append the `×` directly into the text because that's unfortunately the only element that doesn't fit. If not maybe you're going for a flex-box justify-content: space-between type thing where the × should always be on the right and the TODO on the left.

In that case you want the resulting HTML to be like:

```
<div style='display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center'>
<div>To Do text... I need to do stuff</div>
<button onclick='toggleComplete(12)'>×</button>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that for accessibility all clickable elements should really be buttons. If you need yo can cut back on the styling of this button and create a non-button-button class that resets all button specific styles to help you make it still look exactly how you want but work with screen readers.

```js
let form = document.querySelector('#form');
let reset = document.querySelector('#reset');
let myList = document.querySelector('#myList');
let text = document.querySelector('#text');
let submit = document.querySelector('#submit');

submit.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let liDOM = document.createElement('li')
  liDOM.className = 'list-group-item'
  liDOM.innerText = `${text.value[0].toUpperCase()}${text.value.slice(1)}`;
  myList.appendChild(liDOM);

  // This was not working before because `text`
  // was already defined above as `#text`
  var newSpan = document.createElement('span');
  // NOTE: for accessibility this must be a button.
  const closer = document.createElement('span');
  // this is probably what you meant to do... but
  // note this needs some CSS love and the x itself doesn't work if you click
  // on it so maybe just add it to the inner text instead:
  // liDOM.innerText = `${text.value[0].toUpperCase()}${text.value.slice(1)} ×`;
  closer.innerText = '×'
  // perhaps add a special class here that gives it a red color
  // perhaps only add the event listener to this button
  newSpan.className = 'close';
  newSpan.appendChild(closer);
  liDOM.appendChild(newSpan);
});

myList.addEventListener('click', function(item) {
  if (item.target.tagName = 'li') {
    item.target.classList.toggle('checked');
  }
})

let counter = 0;

function myFunction() {
  while (counter < myList.childElementCount) {
    myList.removeChild(myList.firstChild);
  }
}
```

```css
ul li.checked {
  background: #888;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>To Do List</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form">

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 mt-5">

          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="input-group">

                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="text" placeholder="What will you do today?">

                <div class="input-group-append">
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" id="submit">Ekle</button>
                  <button onclick="myFunction()" type="submit" id="reset" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Sıfırla</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card mt-3">
            <div class="card-header">My List</div>
            <ul id="myList" class="list-group list-group-flush">

            </ul>


          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help! Thank you so much.. You explained in AMAZING detail what I needed! ❣